# rescaling text when resizing with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I rescale the text using bootstrap? (a h2 actually)
The problem is that the heading is getting out of its box.
Here is the css box code:

```
.buton{
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    border:2px solid #E3A739;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-top:3em;
    margin-bottom:3em;
}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div id="iteme" class="buton col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <h2>Iteme</h2>
                    </div>
                  .....
```

How can I make the heading resize when I resize the page itself? (I want to make the site responsive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the vw instead of px :

```
.buton h2{
    font-size:3vw;
}
```

You should change the variable as you want it to be, and you can use media queries with it too, because in small devices, it could become invisible with the actual value (3vw) , so you can change it for small devices to be some bigger value.

You can check the browser support for the viewport units in here : [CanIUseIt](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

I hope that this'll help.

Comment: More info can be found on css tricks https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: Thank you for the support @user3766844

Answer (score 3):

What i've seen in alot of website is that they use:

```
font-size: 100%;
```

on their text elements this makes it scale within its parent.
Sometimes it can work sometimes it can become so small its barely readable on a phone. Another option is using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is look into media queries and find out the width or height that the page needs to be edited at.

Look here for help with it: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Answer (score 1):

```
h2{
  font-size:2rem;
}
```

[rems are awesome!](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`vh`, `vw`, `vmin` and `vmax`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html) units to resize text depending on the viewport size.

For example

```
h2 {
  font-size:4vh;
}
```

will size the text of H2 to 4% of the height of the viewport.

I've put an [example JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7e583abb/)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses media queries like so.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```